# Formula inside loop?

Tags: vba, excel

i have applied this formlua where a particular sheet gets opened from a **file** and a particular value which is **selrow** gets looked up in that sheet.
this whole thing is in loop so **file** and selrow both are changing as the i changes.
and sometimes it also possible that **selrow** is not there in sheet or may be the excel **file** which is opened in a loop is not present,in that case i want the value to be zero.

```
Cells(i, "q").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(" &selrow& "","'[" &sheetname& "]Sheet1'!$A$4:$B$4656,2,FALSE),0)"
```

Comment: i have used  Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup but it gives an error when the value is not present in sheet,

Comment: Use `Application.VLookup` instead an you can test the return value using `IsError()`

Comment: I am sorry I did not understand this `excel file which is opened in a loop is not present` Are you referring to `sheetname` ? You will have to show more code especially where you are opening the file and assigning `sheetname`

Comment: @SiddharthRout suppose i am working on sheet A.
there is a folder which contain multiple files, in every loop there is a excel file B which gets opened from that folder a now i lookup a value from file A to File B.

Comment: @SiddharthRout one more thing, the value i am looking up(selrow) is a string. it is always showing zero in the cell(2,"q").
suppose Selrow ="DZ1024" when i =2
the cell( 2,"q") is showing **=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(DZ1024,'[0601 Stock Dump.xlsb]Sheet1'!$A$4:$B$4656,2,FALSE),0)**
it must show "DZ1024" in order to achieve true value